# DataFrame to Panel indexed by nonunique column with Pandas

Tags: python, dataframe, panels, pandas

The following code should do what I want but it takes 10gb of ram by the time it is 20% done with the loop.

```
# In [4]: type(pd)
# Out[4]: pandas.sparse.frame.SparseDataFrame
memid = unique(pd.Member)
pan = {}
for mem in memid:
    pan[mem] = pd[pd.Member==mem]
goal = pandas.Panel(pan)
```

Comment: What are the dimensions (`pd.shape`) and density (`pd.density`) of the SparseDataFrame? Any change you can e-mail me a pickle of the object (`pd.save(file_path)`) for me to have a look to try to diagnose what's up? BTW these questions would be better posed on the mailing list than SO.

Comment: pd.density = 0.12814551216649045 The file is too large to send through email.

Comment: Also, pandas is a great library. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a GitHub issue here.

https://github.com/wesm/pandas/issues/663

I'm pretty sure I identified a circular reference between NumPy ndarray views causing a memory leak. Just committed a fix:

https://github.com/wesm/pandas/commit/4c3916310a86c3e4dab6d30858a984a6f4a64103

Can you install from source and let me know if that fixes your problem?

BTW you might try using SparsePanel instead of Panel because Panel will convert all of the sub-DataFrames to dense form.

Lastly, you might consider using groupby as an alternative to the `O(N * M)` chopping-up of the SparseDataFrame. It's even shorter:

`pan = dict(pd.groupby('Member'))`

Comment: The version I'm running is a git clone from last night. Thanks on the SparsePanel. When I run pan = dict(pd.groupby('Member')) I get: RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object. The actual object takes up less than 1gb when loaded, but the loop causes the ram to slowly get eaten away. I'll direct my questions to the mail list from now on.

Comment: The must be a groupby issue with SparseDataFrame. I'll have to have a look. If you could somehow get me a gzipped pickle of the SparseDataFrame by some means (it should be less than 100 megabytes) I can have a closer look